# PostgreSQL gapless sequence and timestamp field

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with two columns:

1. `n` (an integer)
2. `t` (a timestamp)

> given two rows `(n1, t1)` and `(n2, t2)`it's asked that never occurs
>   that `t2 < t1` when `n1 < n2`.

In addition, the `n` sequence must be gapless.

It is acceptable to have performance loss related to table-level locking.
I'm looking for the most reliable approach here.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.
Transaction isolation level is set to `READ COMMITTED`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33678158/330315

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What about the timestamp? Should I assume that current transaction time will respect my requisites?

Comment: I'd use `clock_timestamp` acquired after the new ID is acquired, so you know you're the newest xact not blocked on a row lock.