# What is the Best Practice to Generate Sequential Code in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, database, postgresql

Let's say I have to use formatted code for my transaction

> for example: 20151208-1-20-xxx : Where xxx is in sequence number
>   (eg: 001,002).

If I have to check the previous transaction code, it would be a problem if the transaction happens in the same time.
What is the best practice to generate this kind of code?

Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a sequence. Create a function for convenience:

```
create table test (code text);
create sequence test_sequence;

create function next_code()
returns text language sql as $$
select format('20151208-1-20-%s', to_char(nextval('test_sequence'), 'FM000'));
$$;

insert into test values (next_code());
insert into test values (next_code());

select * from test;

       code        
-------------------
 20151208-1-20-001
 20151208-1-20-002
(2 rows)
```

Note that though it is probably the simplest effective and safe method, it does not provide gapless sequences.

Read more: [CREATE SEQUENCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) and [Sequence Manipulation Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html).

Check a_horse_with_no_name's answer in [ROLLBACK event triggers in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675967/rollback-event-triggers-in-postgresql/33678158#33678158) for an alternative (gapless) solution.

Comment: Can I reset the sequence everyday without using scheduler/cron/similar?

Comment: Now I see the first part of the code is a date. Does the next part (`1-20`) have special meaning?

Comment: yes, it could be the product type id, or other tables id. I think we can pass variable to the function right?

Comment: Of course, you can use arguments in the `next_code()` function (with `format()` it is easy to properly format the code). You could try to reset the sequence in the function, however it is not quite safe in context of concurrency. Surely I would use `cron`.

Comment: Thank you so much, klin. You got a really nice solution here.