# Postgres: how to set default value to max(value) + 1

Tags: postgresql

How to set a default value to the maximum value of the field + 1.

I tried:

```
,no_af          integer UNIQUE NOT NULL DEFAULT max(no_af)+1
```

but got the answer :

> "ERROR:  ERREUR:  les fonctions d'agrégats ne sont pas autorisés dans
> les expressions par défaut"

Comment: you just need to set it to auto incremental

Comment: Do **not** do that. Use an `identity` or `serial` column

Comment: @Laurenz Albe No but this number si used to reference the job internally.

Comment: Using `serial` and how to fix that numbers are not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad for you that it didn't work. Please please don't do that. Use a sequence instead:

```
,no_af serial UNIQUE NOT NULL
```

If your design requires no holes in the sequence of values, then replace the design with one that allows holes.

Comment: That's the problem, I can't allow holes.. The value is a number that represent the annual number of case we work on.

Comment: But there is no need to store that annual count as an automatically generated number in the database. You can easily find out the number of cases for a year with a query.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using a trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION no_af_incrementation() RETURNS trigger AS $no_af_incrementation$
begin
    if NEW.no_af is NULL then
        NEW.no_af := (select max(no_af)+1 from af.od_af);
    end if;
    return NEW;
end;
```

Comment: This is not going to work correctly if you have concurrent transactions inserting into that table. And how are you going to prevent holes if you allow the value to be specified in an INSERT statement?

Comment: If you truly need a gapless increasing number, consider something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33678158/330315)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The link you posted works perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a `FUNCTION` and use it in the `DEFAULT` defination.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."table_next_id"("table" text)
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."int4" AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
    next_id int4 = 0;
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE format('select max(id)+1 from %s', "table") INTO next_id;       
    RETURN COALESCE(next_id, 1);
END$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE "public"."merchant" (
  "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT table_next_id('merchant'::text),
  "num" int4 NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "merchant_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

I don't know if are there potential problems, especially in concurrent insertes. But it does work.

pg version 15.1